# Permutations and Combinations- which one to use?

Tags: combinatorics

The probability that Ali will answer any one question out of the 10 questions correctly, is 0.6. Each correct answer is worth 4 points.

find in how many ways can Ali receive a grade of 28 out of 40?

I am not sure whether to use permutation formula or the combination formula or something else entirely??? please help.

Comment: Are we assuming that he cannot get partial credit and there are no penalties for wrong answers?

Comment: Yes, we are assuming he's taking the AMC 8, but just the first 10 problems :D

Answer (score 5):

This problem is equivalent to saying:

"How many ways are there to get 7 problems out of 10?"

I'm unsure of why you would mention the probability of getting a problem right, as it doesn't contribute to the question.

The reworded problem would be: $${10\choose 7} = \frac{10!}{7!3!} = \frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}{3\cdot 2} = \boxed{120}$$

So to answer your question, it would be combination, not permutation, as you only need to choose 7 options without rearranging them. Getting #1 right then #2 right is the exact same as getting #2 right then getting #1 right.

Comment: I suspect that the stated problem may be a part of a progression, whereby the student must eventually calculate the probability of scoring 28 out of 40.

Comment: Probably. Too bothered to do that though :D